# Is it possible in MySQL to search a table for where a column only contains 1 comma?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this column in a table which is comma delimited to separate the values.

Here's the sample data:

```
2003,2004
2003,2005
2003,2006
2003,2004,2005
2003,2007
```

I want to get all data that contains only 1 comma.

I've been playing around with the '%' and '_' wildcards, but I can't seem to get the results I need.

`SELECT column FROM table WHERE column like '%_,%'`

Comment: replace the `,` with `''` empty set then take the original length less the replaced length.  if 1 then only 1 comma if > 1 then more than 1 comma.  The length difference would represent the number of commas. `Length(column) - length(Replace(column,',','')) as NumOfCommas`  or `where Length(column) - length(Replace(column,',','')) =1`

Comment: Please use the *appropriate* tags. And don't use "comma delimited values" in a database table. What should be a simple join now becomes a major issue

Comment: You may be able to work with this if you quote the values to make them look like JSON arrays and use JSON functions to find arrays with only two items

Comment: @xQbert .. why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: xQbert hi fella thanks a lot for the answer! I will be searching on millions of data which is why i am trying to lessen the time to loop and try to figure it out with the database only to save time if it is possible..

Comment: Note this will not be terribly efficient as we have to do a length and replace on strings;  so no index use!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `,` with `''` empty set then take the original length less the replaced length. if 1 then only 1 comma if > 1 then more than 1 comma.

The length difference would represent the number of commas.

`Length(column) - length(Replace(column,',','')) as NumOfCommas`

or

```
where Length(column) - length(Replace(column,',','')) =1
```

While this may solve the problem, I agree with what others have indicated.  Storing multiple values in a single column in a RDBMS is asking for more trouble.  Better to normalize the data and get it to at least 3rd Normal form!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `find_in_set()`  method which searches a value in comma separated list, by picking the last value of column using `substring_index` we can then check result of  `find_in_set` should be 2 so that its the second and last value from list

```
select *
from demo
where find_in_set(substring_index(data,',',-1),data) = 2
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/904216/5)

Comment: Creative I like it!

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the answer! I will try to check which one has better speed on retrieving the data. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another solution is to use regular expression in your case it can look like this `^[0-9]{4},[0-9]{4}$` :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColName REGEXP '^[0-9]{4},[0-9]{4}$'
```

Or if you want all non comma one or more time :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColName REGEXP '^[^,]*,[^,]*$'
```